# Calculating MCP in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

QGIS 1.8.0.
Scipy installed.
Statsmodels installed.
Using Sextante to try to calculate MCP.

When I run the MCP calculation from the Toolbox, a layer is added to the file, but the layer doesn't contain any information.

The input layer contains a set of points and the field I select from that layer contains OS grid references.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If you just want to create a Minimum Convex Hull you could use the ftools Convex Hull function. You can find it under Vector -> Geoprocessing -> Convex Hull.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get the same result - a blank layer. What information do either of these tools need in the layer to create the polygon?

Answer (score 1):

Been struggling all day trying to do MCP first with the old "R-related" method, before finding out about the Sextanta "AniMov", and finally installing QGIS 1.8 and the Sextante toolbox. Then had the same "invisible layer" issue. I solved this by discovering that the created MCP layer had no projection. Once I set it the same as the rest of my data, the MCP layer did indeed display correctly. Very simply fix, hope this was all your problem was too.

Answer (score 1):

And if someone is struggling for days to find the AniMove functions as I was, one needs to active the plugin in Processing -> options & configuration -> Providers -> AniMove -> tick box behind activate.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use R/Sextante on QGIS 2.0 to do that. Configure R on Processing ->Options and Configuration and make sure to install libraries "sp", "rgdal", "maptools" and "adehabitatHR". Then go to the toolbox, click on "Create a new R script" and paste the code below. The parameter "percentage" refers to the number of points you wish to include on the calculations.

```
##[Home range]=group
##Layer=vector
##Percentage=number 10
##Field=Field Layer
##Output=Output vector
library(adehabitatHR)
Output<-mcp(Layer[,Field],percent=Percentage)
```

Comment: note that you need the python-rpy2 package to execute R-code through python.