# Render or display only the boundary of a vector layer containing thousands of polygons

Tags: qgis, vector, layers, display

To have a cleaner map to print I want to display only the boundary of a layer composed of more than 200,000 features (all adjacent).

Is there something more straightforward than dissolving or merging all the polygons?

I'm using QGIS.

Comment: may be outdated but possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68735/calculating-mcp-in-qgis

Comment: If you don't want to actually merge your polygons see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8571/how-to-hide-internal-polygon-boundaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS use the dissolve function from menu: Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Dissolve...
This will get you a new table with only the outer perimeter geometry.

Comment: Thanks. I was avoiding this option because it takes 1 day processing, lots of polygons with a 100 attributes. For the dissolve field I had to take an attribute with the same value for all features.

Comment: Well, it takes a few minutes in ArcGIS without attribute selection (the resulting shapefile losses some properties but it is ok for visualization purposes). QGIS with dissolve_all algorithm is not working so far.